# Don't understand the 1st example given for ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I don't understand how the first of the basic examples in [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html) on `ListPlot3D` is generating the plot that it does.

```
ListPlot3D[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}},  Mesh -> All]
```

[image: plot]

Which of these values is it taking as $x$, $y$ and $z$ values and what is the fourth value in each set used for? I'm trying to learn *Mathematica* with zero previous knowledge of arrays, so I don't know if that's the problem or if I'm misunderstanding some completely different aspect.

Comment: From the [details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D.html#139640668): `In ListPlot3D[array], array must be a rectangular array. Each element can be either a single real number representing a  value, or an (x, y, z) triple.
There will be holes in the surface corresponding to array elements that do not represent explicit height values.
ListPlot3D[array] by default takes the x and y coordinate values for each data point to be successive integers starting at 1.`

Comment: @b3m2a1 So then in the example because they aren't triples then each element is a z value: ListPlot3D[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}, 
Mesh -> All]  and it's assigning x and y co-ordinates in integer steps? So would the first element, 1, be assigned x=1,y=1 and the sixth element is x=6,y=6?

Comment: Yeah. The array basically unfurls to this: `MapIndexed[Append[#2, #] &, {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}, {2}]//Flatten[#, 1]&`. But the `Interpolation` is different. You can see the first uses only the array as the mesh whereas using that array gives a full `Mesh` (b.c. it interpolates differently, I think)

Comment: @b3m2a1 So, if I've got this right, it ignores subgroupings? It ignores the fact that the numbers come in sets of four and just makes it into one list of z values?

Comment: I think not quite. Unless I misunderstood the docs, it uses the array indexing, i and j, as x and y.

Comment: If `i` indexes the sublists and `j` indexes the values within the sublists, then plotting `ListPlot3D[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}, Mesh -> All, AxesLabel -> {"j", "i", "value"}]` might clarify things. (It's confused slightly by the fact that the array of values is symmetric -- maybe try playing around with the values).

Comment: You might want to look at [this question and its answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/162935/3066). It is pertinent to what you ask here.

Comment: Do `TraditionalForm[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}]` and you will see how *Mathematica* is interpreting your input: as a collection of single scalar heights arranged in a grid.