# Unexpected behavior of ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting, mesh

This question surfaced when I was working on [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/162916/3066)

Given

```
zVals = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}};
```

and

```
ListPlot3D[zVals, Mesh -> All
```

gives the plot

[image: plot1]

I expected

```
pts = Catenate @ MapIndexed[{Sequence @@ #2, #1} &, zVals, {2}];
ListPlot3D[pts, Mesh -> All]
```

which generates explicit xyz triples to give the same plot, but it doesn't. The vertices are the same, but the triangulation is different. it looks like

[image: plot2]

Can somebody come up with a function or a method that will reproduce the triangulation used by `ListPlot3D`, but which accepts a list of xyz-triples?

Comment: It seems that `ListPlot3D` is generating the first edge of the triangle from the first two sequential points. Permuting the 2nd and 6th point of the catenated list results in precisely 1 re-triangulation. `zc = Catenate@MapIndexed[{Sequence @@ #2, #1} &, zVals, {2}]; ex = 
 zc[[{1, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}]]; ListPlot3D[ex,Mesh->All]` No clue yet what order `ListPlot3D` is generating its points from `zVals` though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation says

```
ListPlot3D[array]
```

requires `array` to be a rectangular shape and that by default it assumes that the `x` and `y` coordinates for each point data point to be successive integers starting at 1.

What it doesn't state is which coordinate, `x` or `y`, changes fastest?

Looking at the examples it is clear that the `x` coordinate is the fastest changing.

So for example:

```
zVals = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}};
```

means that for the first sub-list we would write {x, y, z} by holding the `y` value at a constant value of 1 and allowing `x` to increment from 1 to 4

```
{1, 2, 3, 4} -> {1,1,1}, {2,1,2}, {3,1,3}, {4,1,4}
```

Similarly for the second sublist we hold the `y` value at a constant of 2 and allow `x` to once again increment from 1 to 4

```
{5, 6, 7, 8} -> {1,2,5}, {2,2,6}, {3,2,7}, {4,2,8}
```

and so on.

To convert the `zVals` to `pts` with `{x,y,z}` values use:

```
pts = Flatten[ Table[{j, i, zVals[[i, j]]}, {i, 4}, {j, 4}], 1]

(* {{1, 1, 1},  {2, 1, 2},  {3, 1, 3},  {4, 1, 4},
    {1, 2, 5},  {2, 2, 6},  {3, 2, 7},  {4, 2, 8},
    {1, 3, 9},  {2, 3, 10}, {3, 3, 11}, {4, 3, 12},
    {1, 4, 13}, {2, 4, 14}, {3, 4, 15}, {4, 4, 16}} *)
```

and then

```
ListPlot3D[zVals, Mesh -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot3D[pts, Mesh -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If instead you use

```
pts = Catenate@MapIndexed[{Sequence @@ #2, #1} &, zVals, {2}]
(* {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 3, 3}, {1, 4, 4}, {2, 1, 5}, {2, 
  2, 6}, {2, 3, 7}, {2, 4, 8}, {3, 1, 9}, {3, 2, 10}, {3, 3, 11}, {3, 
  4, 12}, {4, 1, 13}, {4, 2, 14}, {4, 3, 15}, {4, 4, 16}} *)
```

which is equivalent to

```
pts = Flatten[Table[{i, j, zVals[[i, j]]}, {i, 4}, {j, 4}], 1]
(* {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 3, 3}, {1, 4, 4}, {2, 1, 5}, {2, 
  2, 6}, {2, 3, 7}, {2, 4, 8}, {3, 1, 9}, {3, 2, 10}, {3, 3, 11}, {3, 
  4, 12}, {4, 1, 13}, {4, 2, 14}, {4, 3, 15}, {4, 4, 16}} *)
```

the resulting figure has the wrong relationship between `x`, `y` and `z`.

```
ListPlot3D[pts, Mesh -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Update - Triangulation

As pointed out by ***m_goldberg*** the proposed solution has a different triangulation compared to the figure using `zVals`.

That had escaped my notice.

I dissected the figure and discovered that it used `GraphicsComplex` with a list of identical points between the two figures but a different set of polygons (same points, different connection resulting in different polygons).

I have not been able to figure out the rules that Mathematica uses for connecting the points with `Mesh -> All` but I was able to discover that one would get different connections if one input a different order for the points.

By trial and error I stumbled upon that if I took the original set of `{x, y, z}` points (i.e, `pts` with `x` changing most rapidly) and ordered them by what I will call the decrement `x` and increment `y` order, I was able to achieve the same triangulation.

```
pts = Flatten[Table[{j, i, zVals[[i, j]]}, {i, 4}, {j, 4}], 1]
(* {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {3, 1, 3}, {4, 1, 4}, {1, 2, 5}, {2, 
  2, 6}, {3, 2, 7}, {4, 2, 8}, {1, 3, 9}, {2, 3, 10}, {3, 3, 11}, {4, 
  3, 12}, {1, 4, 13}, {2, 4, 14}, {3, 4, 15}, {4, 4, 16}} *)

ptsDecXandIncY = 
 pts[[{4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 12, 11, 10, 9, 16, 15, 14, 13}]]
(* {{4, 1, 4}, {3, 1, 3}, {2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 8}, {3, 
  2, 7}, {2, 2, 6}, {1, 2, 5}, {4, 3, 12}, {3, 3, 11}, {2, 3, 10}, {1,
   3, 9}, {4, 4, 16}, {3, 4, 15}, {2, 4, 14}, {1, 4, 13}} *)

ListPlot3D[ptsDecXandIncY, Mesh -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Unfortunately I am unable to determine what the general rule is for connecting the points.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't seem to bee quit right because the two triangulations are not the same, but are mirror images of each other

Comment: @m_goldberg I agree. I have updated with a section on triangulation. I now get identical results (by trial and error) but am unable to infer he rules Mathematica uses in connecting the points.

Answer (score 4):

`ListPlot3D` maps the values to points with the reverse `{x,y}` order as your construction.

Let's consider the original case first:

```
zVals = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}};
```

Note that this case is symmetric about the plane $x=y$. Let `zc` be your catenation of them to form a list of `{x,y,z}` points.

```
zc = Catenate@MapIndexed[{Sequence @@ #2, #1} &, zVals, {2}];
```

We can plot these both with:

```
ListPlot3D[zVals, Mesh->All, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
ListPlot3D[zc, Mesh->All, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

And, as shown in the question, they will appear essentially identical, with inverted triangulation. This inverted triangulation arises from the transposition of the `x` and `y` components of the mesh used to display them, which can be found by using `InputForm` on the plots.

```
zPoints = InputForm[ListPlot3D[zVals, Mesh -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]][[1, 1, 1]]
zcPoints = InputForm[ListPlot3D[zc, Mesh -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]][[1, 1, 1]]
(zcPoints /. {x_,y_,z_}->{y,x,z}) == zPoints
```

A more obvious visual example can be had with this set of `z` values, which are not symmetric about $x=y$:

```
zVals = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {-1, -2, -3, -4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, {-4, -3, -2, -1}};
zc = Catenate@MapIndexed[{Sequence @@ #2, #1} &, zVals, {2}];
```

In this case, the two plots are clearly inverted:

```
ListPlot3D[zVals, Mesh->All, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
ListPlot3D[zc, Mesh->All, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

As for why `ListPlot3D` behaves this way, I do not know.

A graph equivalent to the output of `ListPlot3D[zVals]` can be generated by taking the list of `z` points with `x` and `y` swapped, e.g.:

```
z2 = Flatten[Table[{j, i, zVals[[i, j]]},
          {i, 1, Length[zVals]}, {j, 1, Length[zVals[[1]]]}], 1];
ListPlot3D[z2, Mesh -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

Answer (score 2):

A function that will generate the same surface as ListPlot3D can be written as follows:

```
listPlot3DFromZ[zVals : {__}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{pts}, 
    pts = Catenate[Reverse /@ MapIndexed[{#2[[2]], #2[[1]], #1} &, zVals, {2}]];
    ListPlot3D[pts, opts]]
```

`listPlot3DFromZ` is a generalization of the solution that Jack LaVigne presented in the update to his answer.

I don't believe even for a moment that `ListPlot3D` converts an array argument like this function does. I believe it generates the `GraphicsComplex` it outputs by more direct methods.

#### Karacoreable's example

Here is the plot form the original question, reproduced correctly.

```
With[{zvals = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}}, 
  GraphicsRow[
    {listPlot3DFromZ[zvals,
       Mesh -> All,
       AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
       BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}],
     ListPlot3D[zvals,
       Mesh -> All,
       AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
       BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]}]]
```

[image: plots1]

#### Jack LaVigne's and eyorble's examples

Here are the plots from Jack LaVigne's and eyorble's  answers, both also reproduced correctly.

```
With[{zvals = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}}}, 
  GraphicsRow[
    {listPlot3DFromZ[zvals,
       Mesh -> All,
       AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
       BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}],
     ListPlot3D[zvals,
       Mesh -> All,
       AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
       BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]}]]
```

[image: plots2]

```
With[{zvals = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {-1, -2, -3, -4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}, {-4, -3, -2, -1}}, 
  GraphicsRow[
    {listPlot3DFromZ[zvals,
       Mesh -> All,
       AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
       BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}],
     ListPlot3D[zvals,
       Mesh -> All,
       AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
       BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]}]]
```

[image: plot3]